# C# Unity. Calling a method if it exists within a certain gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've tried looking around online for a solution to this problem, but I just can't seem to find anything. In my game, I have an Interactor (The Player) and and the Interacted (The target object). What I'm trying to is find a way to check that the object that I've chosen to interact with has a MonoBehaviour that contains the Method "Interacted", and if it does, run it.

This is what my code looks like now, or at least the important bit. OnInteract runs fine when the interaction is selected. The foreach loop will also correctly return each MonoBehaviour in the Transform selected. I can't, however, run a method after getting its MonoBehaviour because it doesn't recognize the method as existing yet. Is there a way for me to check whether or not the method exists and then run it, or should I be taking a different route entirely? Thank You.

Comment: [`GameObject.SendMessage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

So there's a smart way to do this and a dumb/brute-force way.

The smart way is to give all MonoBehaviours you intend to interact with an interface like so:

```
public interface IInteractable
{
    void Interacted();
}
```

and then implement the interface in all required MonoBehaviours, which forces you to implement the Interacted method:

```
public class InteractableMonobehaviour12 : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
```

Which you can then make use of by checking:

```
if (interacted.TryGetComponent<IInteractable>(out IInteractable interactable))
    interactable.Interacted();
```

The dumb way is to do exactly as you asked and iterate through all Monobehaviours and then search for the method in them - you can achieve this with C# Reflection, but in this case it is absolutely not required unless you have no control over the classes you want to call Interacted on, so I will spare you the details. If you do want to dive into that, the first code example on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/dynamically-loading-and-using-types) looks up a types method and executes it without compile-time constraints and checks.

In case you expect multiple components to implement IInteractable on one object, you might want to iterate over the MonoBehaviours anyway if you get a first match, just in case there is a second (I don't think GetComponents works here with interfaces, although that might have changed).
In that case, you can check if the MonoBehaviour implements that interface:

```
if (component is IInteractable)
    ((IInteractable)component).Interacted();
```

Comment: Don't use `GetComponent` twice ... rather use e.g. `(interacted.TryGetComponent<IInteractable>(out var interactable))`

Comment: Fair point, left it that way for simplicity. Will fix it

Comment: Let's hope that version does work with interfaces, haven't tested.
Note to OP: Using an interface in a GetComponent call instead of an actual Monobehaviour is a bit unusual but works best in this case, though I've heard GetComponent*s* does not support that.